# ctools_modal_render() in a condition

Tags: 7, chaos-tool-suite

I have the following code in my custom.module (using it in `hook_init()`):

```
if ($js) {
  // Required includes for ctools to work:
  ctools_include('modal');
  ctools_include('ajax');
}

if (user_is_logged_in()) {
  $title = 'hello';
  $output = 'more hellos';
  ctools_modal_render($title, $output);
} else {
  return NULL;
}
```

Problem is if even i'm not logged it shows to me a modal windows with infinite loading text. How to unset `ctools_modal_render()` if i am not logged in?

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to redirect anonymous user to user login page.

```
if ($js) {
  // Required includes for ctools to work:
  ctools_include('modal');
  ctools_include('ajax');
}

if (user_is_logged_in()) {
  $title = 'hello';
  $output = 'more hellos';
  ctools_modal_render($title, $output);
} else {

  ctools_ajax_command_redirect('user/login');
  ctools_modal_command_dismiss();

}
```

Or, If you do not want to display popup to anonymous user, then you need to check user is anonymous or not before redering the ctools popup link.

```
<?php if (user_is_logged_in()): ?>
<a href="your_link" class="ctools-use-modal ctools-modal-[yourpopupclass]">Link 1</a>
<?php else: ?>
<a href="user/login">Login</a>
<?php endif; ?>
```